# write matrix to image by PIL

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

I have a 2D matrix that I want to write as a PBM file (it's only -1,1 values, black&white).

I just discovered about PIL, but the following approach does not work:

```
im = Image.new('L', (self.nx,self.ny))  
data=[[255*(self.spins[i][j][0].m+1)/2 for j in range(0,self.ny)]for i in range(0,self.nx)]  
im.putdata(data)   
im.save('my_image.pbm')
```

that is, I get my PBM file with its header, but no data:

```
P5  
4 3  
255
```

if somebody can help me here...

thank you!

alessandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image.putdata takes a one-dimensional sequence, not a multi-dimensional sequence like what you've got in your code.

I.e. instead of using something like

```
[[v1, v2, v3],
 [v4, v5, v6],
 [v7, v8, v9]]
```

to hold your pixel data that is being passed to putdata, it should be

```
[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9]
```

Comment: BTW, solved by this:  
data=[255*(self.spins[i][j][0].m+1)/2 for j in range(0,self.ny) for i in range(0,self.nx)]  

I just wish however that PIL would  output some error code in cases like this...
where can I find some good introduction to it?

Comment: The online documentation for PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) is excellent.